# Save in my database and check api once in a day (Strapi + react)

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I'm building an app to check the position of the keywords in Google (just to learn). I use strapi and react.

I want to save the results I get with the api in my database and check these results only once in a day.

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a cronjob to do that.

1. enable the cronjob: add on config/server.js the following: cron: { enabled: true }
2. Add a function under config/functions/cron.js

   ```
    module.exports = {
    '* * 22 * *': async () => {
        console.log('I ran everyday at 22:00 / 10:00pm ');
        //add your logic here
    },
    };
   ```

Comment: hi ! to use cronjob you have to use a npm package or you can do it directly like your code above ?

Comment: you can use it with the code above. No need to add the package, strapi uses under the hood node-schedule